# Facebook feed layout

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout

I know my question may be stupid, but I'm starting to develop some prototypes for a personal application and I would like the page layout of this application was similar to the page of facebook feeds, on a android plataform. So, i would like to know: what is the component in this image?

https://www.facebook.com/images/mobile/marketing/timeline/linkShare.png

Its a custom ListView? If not, could someone tell me how to get this? Again, I am newbie in development of layouts and therefore I am asking this question. haha

Comment: if you have a device running Android JellyBean (4.1-3), then you can use the DDMS tool to produce an XML screenshot which will list all the  views used in the screenshot

Comment: Wow, I did not know that the DDMS made ​​this type of service. Thanks for the help, @panini :)